# Get Tooltip working inside a disabled tab

Tags: jquery, bootstrap-4, tooltip

Consider the following:

```
<ul class="nav nav-tabs">
  <li class="nav-item">
    <a class="nav-link active diabled" data-toggle="tab" href="#home">Home</a>
    <i class="fas fa-circle missing-data" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="Missing Data"></i>
  </li>
  <li class="nav-item">
    <a class="nav-link diabled" data-toggle="tab" href="#menu1">Menu 1</a>
  </li>
  <li class="nav-item">
    <a class="nav-link diabled" data-toggle="tab" href="#menu2">Menu 2</a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

With the following JS:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('body').tooltip({
    selector: '[data-toggle="tooltip"]',
    html: true,
  });
});
```

What I am trying to do **without re-enabling the tabs** is have the tool tip work, while inside a `nav-item` thats been `disabled`.

**Any thoughts?**

*This currently does not work.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, in your code sample, you spelled **disabled** wrong.

In bootstrap4, `nav-item` is optional when building a tab. You can build a tab by just having a `nav` and `nav-link`s.

The tooltip works inside a `nav-item`, as well as a disabled `nav-link`:

```
<ul class="nav nav-tabs">
    <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link active disabled" data-toggle="tab" href="#home">Home
            <i class="fas fa-circle missing-data" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="Missing Data"></i>
        </a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link disabled" data-toggle="tab" href="#menu1">Menu 1
            <i class="fas fa-circle missing-data" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="Missing Data"></i></a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link disabled" data-toggle="tab" href="#menu2">Menu 2
            <i class="fas fa-circle missing-data" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="Missing Data"></i></a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

[image]

https://jsfiddle.net/davidliang2008/fjw5c67d/8/